# Unit test failing for custom processor's 'optional' properties

Tags: apache-nifi

To create a custom processor, I followed [the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Maven+Projects+for+Extensions#MavenProjectsforExtensions-LinkingProcessorsandControllerServices).

I made the necessary code changes in the MyProcessor.java and the MyProcessorTest runs fine except when I try to use some 'optional' properties. Note : I tried all the builder methods like required(false), addValidator() etc. for the optional properties, in vain. Actually, a validator doesn't make sense for an optional property ...

**MyProcessor.java**

```
@Tags({ "example" })
@CapabilityDescription("Provide a description")
@SeeAlso({})
@ReadsAttributes({ @ReadsAttribute(attribute = "", description = "") })
@WritesAttributes({ @WritesAttribute(attribute = "", description = "") })
@Stateful(description = "After a db-level LSN is processed, the same should be persisted as the last processed LSN", scopes = { Scope.CLUSTER })
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
public static final Relationship REL_SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder()
.name("success")
.description(
"Successfully created FlowFile from SQL query result set.")
.build();
public static final Relationship REL_FAILURE = new Relationship.Builder()
.name("failure").description("SQL query execution failed. ???")
.build();


/* Start : Mandatory properties */
public static final PropertyDescriptor DBCP_SERVICE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
.name("Database Connection Pooling Service")
.description(
"The Controller Service that is used to obtain connection to database")
.required(true).identifiesControllerService(DBCPService.class)
.build();


public static final PropertyDescriptor CONTAINER_DB = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
.name("containerDB").displayName("Container Database")
.description("The name of the container database").required(true)
.addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR).build();
...
...more mandatory properties
...

/* End : Mandatory properties */


/*Start : Optional properties */
public static final PropertyDescriptor CDC_TS_FROM = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
.name("cdcTSFrom").displayName("Load CDC on or after")
.description("The CDC on or after this datetime will be fetched.")
.required(false).defaultValue(null).build();


public static final PropertyDescriptor SCHEMA = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
.name("schema").displayName("DB Schema")
.description("The schema which contains the xxxxxx")
.defaultValue(null).required(false).build();

/*End : Optional properties */


private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors;
private Set<Relationship> relationships;

@Override
protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {
final List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new ArrayList<PropertyDescriptor>();
descriptors.add(CONTAINER_DB);
descriptors.add(DBCP_SERVICE);
...
...
...
descriptors.add(CDC_TS_FROM);
descriptors.add(SCHEMA);
...
...
...
this.descriptors = Collections.unmodifiableList(descriptors);
final Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<Relationship>();
relationships.add(REL_FAILURE);
relationships.add(REL_SUCCESS);
this.relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
}
@Override
public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
return this.relationships;
}
@Override
public final List<PropertyDescriptor> getSupportedPropertyDescriptors() {
return descriptors;
}
// TODO : Check if the component lifecycle methods esp. onScheduled() and
// onShutDown() are required
@Override
public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context,
final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
...
...
...
}

}
```

**MyProcessorTest.java**

```
public class MyProcessorTest {
private TestRunner testRunner;
private final String CONTAINER_DB = "test";
private final String DBCP_SERVICE = "test_dbcp";
...
...
...

private final String SCHEMA = "dbo";
private final String CDC_TS_FROM = "";
...
...
...
@Before
public void init() throws InitializationException {
testRunner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(MyProcessor.class);
final DBCPService dbcp = new DBCPServiceSQLServerImpl(...);
final Map<String, String> dbcpProperties = new HashMap<>();
testRunner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(MyProcessor.class);
testRunner.addControllerService(DBCP_SERVICE, dbcp, dbcpProperties);
testRunner.enableControllerService(dbcp);
testRunner.assertValid(dbcp);
testRunner.setProperty(MyProcessor.DBCP_SERVICE, DBCP_SERVICE);
testRunner.setProperty(MyProcessor.CONTAINER_DB, CONTAINER_DB);
...
...
...

testRunner.setProperty(MyProcessor.CDC_TS_FROM, CDC_TS_FROM);
testRunner.setProperty(MyProcessor.SCHEMA, SCHEMA);
...
...
...
}
@Test
public void testProcessor() {
testRunner.run();
}
/**
 * Simple implementation only for MyProcessor processor testing.
 */
private class DBCPServiceSQLServerImpl extends AbstractControllerService
implements DBCPService {
private static final String SQL_SERVER_CONNECT_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://%s;database=%s";
private String containerDB;
private String password;
private String userName;
private String dbHost;
public DBCPServiceSQLServerImpl(String containerDB, String password,
String userName, String dbHost) {
super();
this.containerDB = containerDB;
this.password = password;
this.userName = userName;
this.dbHost = dbHost;
}
@Override
public String getIdentifier() {
return DBCP_SERVICE;
}
@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws ProcessException {
try {
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(String
.format(SQL_SERVER_CONNECT_URL, dbHost, containerDB),
userName, password);
return connection;
} catch (final Exception e) {
throw new ProcessException("getConnection failed: " + e);
}
}
}
}
```

Now if I comment the optional properties in the test class :

```
//testRunner.setProperty(MyProcessor.CDC_TS_FROM, CDC_TS_FROM);

//testRunner.setProperty(MyProcessor.SCHEMA, SCHEMA);
```

, the test completes normally but if I enable any or all of the optional properties, say, CDC_TS_FROM, then I the test case assertion fails, no matter what value I put for CDC_TS_FROM :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Processor has 1 validation failures:
'cdcTSFrom' validated against '' is invalid because 'cdcTSFrom' is not a supported property
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.apache.nifi.util.MockProcessContext.assertValid(MockProcessContext.java:251)
at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.run(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:161)
at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.run(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:152)
at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.run(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:147)
at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.run(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:142)
at org.apache.nifi.util.StandardProcessorTestRunner.run(StandardProcessorTestRunner.java:137)
at processors.NiFiCDCPoC.sqlserver.MyProcessorTest.testProcessor(MyProcessorTest.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Edit-1 :

I added two(?) validators :

```
public static final PropertyDescriptor CDC_TS_FROM = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("cdcTSFrom").displayName("Load CDC on or after")
            .description("The CDC on or after this datetime will be fetched.")
            .required(false).defaultValue(null).addValidator(Validator.VALID)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.TIME_PERIOD_VALIDATOR).build();
```

Error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Processor has 1 validation failures:
'cdcTSFrom' validated against '2017-03-06 10:00:00' is invalid because Must be of format <duration> <TimeUnit> where <duration> is a non-negative integer and TimeUnit is a supported Time Unit, such as: nanos, millis, secs, mins, hrs, days
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Property Descriptors (required or optional) must have a Validator set explicitly, otherwise it will return the error you are seeing. It appears you are not looking to perform validation, but you still must set a validator, so on your optional properties add the following to the builder:

```
.addValidator(Validator.VALID)
```

**EDIT** (see comments below): Marking the PropertyDescriptor as `required(false)` allows it to be an optional property and thus can have no value specified. If the user enters a value, and you want to validate that against certain rules, you can add that particular Validator (or write your own and add that). For a Time Period (2 seconds, e.g.), and for other cases, there are a set of built-in validators, for example allowing only values between 2 and 20 seconds:

```
    .addValidator(StandardValidators.createTimePeriodValidator(
       2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS
    ))
```

Comment: If a property is optional (it may be null or may be a timestamp/string), how do I specify a validator ?

Comment: The way I put in my answer, add VALID as the validator, that will mark any value (or lack thereof) as valid.

Comment: Yeah I got that but in case a user specifies a Timestamp/period, this 'Valid' Validator won't suffice, how do I handle that case ?

Comment: If you want to support two disparate validation strategies, you'll need to build a custom validator with that internal logic. The `StandardValidators` class has good examples of these to reference.

Comment: can you check 'Edit-1' to my answer ? Since I need Time period validator, I added two validators but it didn't work out ...

Comment: You don't need to add VALID because you are already adding a different validator. Adding VALID is only necessary if you aren't going to actually be validating your input

Comment: You added a Time Period validator not a time stamp validator. I don't think a time stamp validator exists in the built in set, you will need to write your own (see Andy's comment) and add that instead of a Time Period validator

Comment: Ok, maybe I will proceed with a custom validator for timestamp but is it possible to implement the following using the same validator : 1. The custom validator will allow/pass the null/empty values 2. If some value is present, it should be in a prescribed timestamp format

Comment: Yes there are examples of such validators in either StandardValidators and/or various processors in the NiFi codebase